# SelectList selected values not assigning from an array of integers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

How can I set the selectedvalue property of a `SelectList`

```
   var attributeSet = attribute.AttributeSetAttributes.Where(c => c.AttributeSetID == id).Select(c => c.AttributeID).ToArray();

   var attributeList = new SelectList(db.CatAttributes.Where(c => c.IsActive), "ID", "FullName", attributeSet);
    ViewBag.AttributesList = attributeList;
```

and in Views i used it like that

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Attributes, (SelectList)ViewBag.AttributesList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In above `attributeSet` get `integer` values whose selected property should be true in `SelectList => attributeList`, If i give only one value it shows selected property = `true`, but when i pass an array or list it won't set the selected property = `true`.

Comment: Use `MultiSelectList`, but its not really necessary to add the the last parameter if your binding to a property - `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.attributeSet. Model.attributeList)` because its the value of the property that determines what is selected (the last parameter is just ignored)

Comment: Show your Model and View

Comment: @StephenMuecke see my edit

Comment: Based on your edit, there is no reason to add the last parameter of the `SelectList` constructor (it will be ignored anyway). If `model.Attributes` is an `IEnumerable<int>` (equal to `attributeSet`) then it just needs to be `var attributeList = new SelectList(db.CatAttributes.Where(c => c.IsActive), "ID", "FullName");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i fixed it, I used MultiSelectList instead of SelectList, and passed third parameter as an array

```
var attributeSet = attribute.AttributeSetAttributes.Where(c => c.AttributeSetID == id).Select(c => c.AttributeID).ToArray();

var attributeList = new MultiSelectList(db.CatAttributes.Where(c => c.IsActive), "ID", "FullName");
ViewBag.AttributesList = attributeList;

var model = new AttributeSetViewModel()
        {
            AttributeSet = attribute, Attributes = attributeSet
        };
```

and in Views

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Attributes, (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.AttributesList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This sets my selected property = true.

Thanks @Stephen Muecke for idea !!

Comment: As I noted, this is pointless. Just use `myModel.Attributes = attributeSet; return View(myModel);` and delete the last parameter of the `SelectList` constructor (that's how model binding works!)